# MySQL value near by, join, abs with dynamic value

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal is the get the price of the nearest number of the m3 and weight and put this in a table.

This sample works for me. But i hard code `m3`,`weight`,`country` and `transportername`

Query1:

```
SELECT
  country,
  transportername,
  ABS(m3-0.5) as ABS_M3 ,
  m3,
  ABS(weight-5) as ABS_weight,
  weight,
  price
FROM database.transportcost
WHERE   m3      >= 0.5    AND
        weight  >= 5      AND
        country = "GB"    AND
        transportername like '%aa%'
Group by transportername
Order by ABS(m3-0.5) +
         ABS(weight-5) +
         price
```

Now i want to get the hard code value from a other table. I don't know what value i need to put in `~~xx.volumen~~` and `~~xx.gewicht~~`.

Query2:

```
INSERT INTO database.transportcostPerItem (sku,country,transportname,weight,m3,price)
SELECT g.orderitemid, p2.country, p2.transportername, p2.weight, p2.m3, p2.price
FROM database.orderitem g
JOIN database.order i                 on i.orderid     = g.orderid
JOIN database.matrixtable xx       on g.orderitemid = xx.sku
JOIN database.vlog cc                on i.orderid     = cc.orderid
JOIN
(
  SELECT   *
  FROM database.transportcost
  Group by transportername
  Order by ABS(m3-~~xx.volumen~~) +
           ABS(weight-~~xx.gewicht~~) +
           price
) as p2 on p2.country          = i._country            AND
           p2.transportername  = cc._transportername   AND
           p2.weight           = xx.gewicht            AND
           p2.m3               = xx.volumen

;
```

Edit:

Sample data

```
Table: database.transportcost

country | transportername | m3     | weight | price
--------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------
GB      | aa              |  50.00 |    50  |  77.70
GB      | bb              |   0.50 |   125  |  83.19
GB      | cc              |   0.50 |   125  |  96.03
GB      | bb              |   0.60 |   150  |  83.19
GB      | aa              |  75.00 |    75  |  89.04
GB      | cc              |   0.60 |   150  |  96.03
GB      | dd              |  50.00 |    50  | 163.38
GB      | cc              |   0.70 |   175  |  96.03
GB      | bb              |   0.70 |   175  |  96.85
GB      | ee              |   0.53 |   175  | 102.78
GB      | gg              |   0.53 |   175  | 110.37
GB      | aa              | 100.00 |   100  |  89.04
GB      | cc              |   0.80 |   200  |  96.03
GB      | bb              |   0.80 |   200  |  96.85
GB      | ff              |   0.60 |   200  | 110.33
DE      | aaa             |   0.50 |    50  |  26.40
DE      | bbb             |   0.50 |    75  |  31.84
DE      | aaa             |   0.75 |    75  |  34.19
DE      | ccc             |   0.50 |   100  |  34.17
DE      | bbb             |   0.67 |   100  |  35.47
DE      | ccc             |   1.00 |   100  |  37.59
DE      | ddd             |   0.50 |   100  |  62.38
DE      | ccc             |   0.63 |   125  |  43.04
DE      | bbb             |   0.83 |   125  |  44.24
DE      | aaa             |   0.93 |   125  |  45.84
DE      | eee             |   0.50 |   125  |  53.80
DE      | fff             |   0.50 |   125  |  54.02
```

`Query 1` results for the country `GB`

```
country | transportername | ABS_M3                | m3    | ABS_weight | weight | price
--------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------
GB      | aa              | 49.5                  | 50.00 | 45         |  50    |  77.70
GB      | bb              |  0                    |  0.50 | 120        | 125    |  83.19
GB      | cc              |  0                    |  0.50 | 120        | 125    |  96.03
GB      | dd              | 49.5                  | 50.00 | 45         |  50    | 163.38
GB      | ee              |  0.030000000000000027 |  0.53 | 170        | 175    | 102.78
GB      | gg              |  0.030000000000000027 |  0.53 | 170        | 175    | 110.37
```

`Query 1` results for the country `DE`

```
country | transportername | ABS_M3 | m3   | ABS_weight | weight | price
--------+-----------------+--------+------+------------+--------+-------
DE      | aaa             | 0      | 0.50 |  45        |   50   |  26.40
DE      | bbb             | 0      | 0.50 |  70        |   75   |  31.84
DE      | ccc             | 0      | 0.50 |  95        |  100   |  34.17
DE      | ddd             | 0      | 0.50 |  95        |  100   |  62.38
DE      | eee             | 0      | 0.50 | 120        |  125   |  53.80
DE      | fff             | 0      | 0.50 | 120        |  125   |  54.02
DE      | ggg             | 0      | 0.50 | 195        |  200   |  87.29
```

Results in the end `Query 2` should look like this:

```
Table: database.transportcostPerItem

orderitemid | country | transportername | m3  | weight | price
------------+---------+-----------------+-----+--------+------
1           | GB      | aa              | 0,5 | 5      | 77.70
2           | DE      | aaa             | 0,5 | 5      | 26.40
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  A clear question would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Add samples

Comment: Your queries are invalid. You group by trasportername, but don't tell the DBMS what aggregation values you want to get. MySQL lets this slip and picks values arbitrarily. For instance it could pick m3 = 100.00, weight = 75, price = 77.70 for transporter aa and this result would be valid, because you didn't say whether you wanted the maximum m3 or the minimum or whichever. Obviously the DBMS picked 50.00 / 50 / 77.70 for transportername aa, but that's a random result you cannot rely upon.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right i should have to put a limit in there.. btw how did you design the results table like that?

Comment: Your queries cannot be fixed with a "limit". If you group by `transportername`, then your select list must only contain `transportername` and aggregations, such as `min(m3)`, `max(price)`, `avg(weight)` and the like. You may want to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` so as not to allow MySQL to let such queries unnoticed. With this mode set, you'd get an error telling you that you are selcting values that are not specified by group or aggregation function.

Comment: As to formatting: I do this manually in a text editor. Make sure not to use tabs, but blanks instead. Then put <pre> before and </pre> after the table, so as to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are merely looking for the cheapest transport for given m3 and weight. In a first step you'd find all transports for at least the m3 and weight given. Of these you pick the lowest price then.

```
select *
from transportcost
where country = 'GB'
  and m3 >= 0.5
  and weight >= 5
order by price
limit 1;
```

If you wanted the measures closest to your given m3 and weight instead, even if that transport would be more expensive, you could order by the sum of the percentages:

```
select *
from transportcost
where country = 'GB'
  and m3 >= 0.5
  and weight >= 5
order by m3 / 0.5 + weight / 5, price
limit 1;
```

Now instead of given m3, weight, country, and transporter name, you get the values from an order details table. If this were just about a single order details record, the approach would be exactly the same, only instead of comparing with fixed values (`m3 >= 0.5`) you'd compare with the order details record's values (`transportcost.m3 >= orderdetail.m3`). Alas, with multiple order details records this approach doesn't work anymore, because we cannot limit the results to one row, but need one row per order details record instead. This would be solved with window functions (`ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` etc.) or lateral joins (`CROSS APPLY`) in standard SQL. MySQL features neither.

Here is how to join the transport cost table:

```
select *
from <your order tables>
join transportcost tc
where tc.country = i._country 
  and tc._transportername = cc._transportername 
  and tc.m3 >= xx.volumen
  and tc.weight >= xx.gewicht;
```

And now you must find a way to rank your results, so as to only get the best match per order detail. One way is to emulate `ROW_NUMBER` with variables. You may want to look this up in other answers. Another would be a limit subquery in the `SELECT clause`, but for this to work you need a single column identifying a record in the transport cost table. Let's say you add a column called `ID` and fill it with unique values...

```
select <some order columns>, tc.*
from
(
  select <some order columns>,
    (
      select id
      from transportcost tc
      where tc.country = i._country 
        and tc._transportername = cc._transportername 
        and tc.m3 >= xx.volumen
        and tc.weight >= xx.gewicht
      order by tc.m3 / xx.volumen + tc.weight / xx.gewicht, tc.price
      limit 1
    ) as best_transportcost_id
  from <your order tables>
) data
join transportcost tc
where tc.id = data.best_transportcost_id;
```

(You could do this without an ID somehow by concatenating the values, e.g. 'GB-aa-50.00-50-77.70', so as to have a string identifying a transport cost record, but I don't recommend this. It's better to have a unique ID with an index for quick lookups. And even better would be to work with a better DBMS :-)

Comment: Some how i can't get it to work... where do i need to put the joins? ....FROM database.orderitem g
JOIN database.order i                 on i.orderid     = g.orderid
JOIN database.matrixtable xx       on g.orderitemid = xx.sku
JOIN database.vlog cc                on i.orderid     = cc.orderid

Comment: Well, you'd replace `from <your order tables>`. I don't understand your tables anyway :-) What does the `matrixtable` contain? As it contains weight and volume, I'd rather expect an `item` table there joined on `itemid`. And `vlog` contains all allowed transportes for an order? Or why are there multiple `vlog` per `orderid`? It would be helpful to understand the tables. What are their primary keys? What do they represent? It seems there is no reason at all to join the `orders` table by the way.

Comment: this one is not working like it should be.. i removed the `matrixtable`.. `xx.gewicht` become's `o._weightReal`  and `xx.volumen` become's `o._m3`..  vlog there are the information when something is send.. Transportcost has a new field `id`. There aren't really primary keys.. it's more like a noslq database. it's hard to find a way in it...

Comment: So far we have no table with the alias `o`. Did you mean `g` = `orderitem` maybe? And if one order contains two orderitems A and B and two vlogs are related to that order, one for transporter a and one for transporter b, how do we now which transporter transported which item?

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution of @Thorsten.

This is the results

```
    INSERT INTO database.transportcostperitem (transportcostID, orderID, sku, country, transportername, weight, m3,price,shippingmethod,shippingstatus,shippingDate)
SELECT  
        transportcostID, 
        orderID,
        sku, 
        _country,
        transportername,
        transportTmp._weightReal,
        transportTmp._m3  ,
        price, 
        _shippingMethod,
        _shippingStatus,
        _shippingDate
FROM(

    SELECT 
        b.orderID,
        o.sku,      
        b.transporter,      
        o._country, 
        i._shippingMethod,
        i._shippingStatus,
        i._shippingDate,
        o._m3,
        o._weightReal,
        ( 

                SELECT  id
                FROM database.transportcost tc
                where
                    tc.transportername      = b._transporterName    AND
                    tc.country              = o._country            AND
                    tc.weight               >= o._weightReal        AND 
                    tc.m3                   >= o._m3
                order by    o._m3 / tc.m3  +  o._weightReal / tc.weight , tc.price
                limit 1

        ) as transportcostID
    FROM database.orderitem             o
    JOIN database.order                 i       on i.orderID = o.orderID 
    JOIN database.vlog                  b       on b.orderID = o.orderID    
    WHERE sku >0 

)as transportTmp
JOIN database.transportcost tc
where   tc.id = transportcostID     AND
        _shippingMethod is not null
orderID by sku
;
```